# Como construir esta expressão regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

estou tentando construir uma expressão regular e está um pouco difícil.

Gostaria que me ajudassem, e se possível explicar como o computador trabalha em relação a esta expressão que estou pedindo.

Eu preciso pegar tudo no começo de uma String, até que um grupo de Strings seja encontrada, por exemplo:

Eu quero pegar do começo da String até que seja encontrado "2.8" ou "6v" ou "2p".

Obrigado.

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com/ essa ferramenta ajuda demais na construção de expressões regulares.

Comment: Essas sub-strings "2.8" ou "6v" ou "2p" são dinâmicas certo? elas estão numa array? ou vais ter de escrever à mão?

Comment: Não! Eu vou definir algo em torno de 3 ou 4 grupos de Strings que serão sempre estas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/^(.)+(?=([\d+]\.?[\d+]|\d\w))/g`

```
^(.)+
(?=
    (
        [\d+]\.?[\d+]
        |
        \d\w
    )
)
```

Essa expressão vai obter qualquer texto que venha antes de "0.0" ou "0x".

*Explicação da expressão:*

- `^(.)+` qualquer texto desde o inicio da string
- `(?=)` o texto deve ser seguido pela seguinte expressão:
- `[\d+]\.?[\d+]` dígito ponto dígito, ou...
- `\d\w` dígito e uma letra

Comment: Sua solução foi a que funcionou da forma que eu queria, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
/((^[\s\S]+)2\.8)|((^[\s\S]+)6v)|((^[\s\S]+)2p)/g
```

Explicando:

`[\s\S]` pega tudo.

`+` pega todos os caracteres que satisfizerem a condição anterior, portanto "tudo de tudo".

`^` indica o começo da String, então eu coloquei antes de buscar "tudo".

Depois disso, basta colocar onde você quer que a busca pare. Os parênteses são para fins de organização, para deixar tudo separadinho.

`|` é um operador "ou". Eu apenas coloquei o mesmo código 3 vezes, mudando apenas a condição de parada.

`\.` é para buscar pelo ponto. Eu havia esquecido de acrescentar mas editei.

Eis um exemplo: http://regexr.com/3evn9